# turf problems and turf recovery

Tags: identification, plant-health, grass

[image][image]I live in portugal, and after  Summer holidays I found the lawn infested with the grass in the photo. the lawn have a lot of sunny, watered during the night, and the terrain is sandy.
I have about 50% of the affected lawn. On another similar lawn, but with more shade, it does not appear.
What can i do to recover the lawn?

sorry my english is not the best

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the photo you mentioned.

Comment: Não se trata de Panicum repens. é uma graninea suave e não aspera e dura tal como o Panicum